# Polygon query in Redisearch

Tags: elasticsearch, redisearch

[RediSearch](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/RediSearch) looks promising after reading https://redislabs.com/blog/search-benchmarking-redisearch-vs-elasticsearch/. 
We use elasticsearch currently. We rely heavily on its polygon query feature https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-query.html.

I couldn't find polygon query in RediSearch. Is it there under different name? Is there anyone out using RediSearch for polygon query? How do you achieve that?

For now, only option I see is to use [Geo filter](https://github.com/RediSearch/JRediSearch/blob/master/src/main/java/io/redisearch/Query.java#L76) to get points in different circles, and then find intersection of those with my polygon in application code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the exact same boat, and it seems like as of v1.4.8 geo filters are limited to geo radius filters. However, it does look like an issue was created to add support for geo polygon filters:

https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/RediSearch/issues/680